# Microphone of headset is not detected at all

Tags: audio, microphone, pipewire

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad S145 laptop running Fedora 38. Recently I bought a headset where the microphone and the headphones use the same plug.

However, the microphone isn't detected. `pavucontrol` says the headset microphone is disconnected and, indeed, all the audio capture seems to be coming from the laptop's microphone.

The audio codec on my machine is ALC236:

```
$ grep Codec /proc/asound/card*/codec*             
/proc/asound/card1/codec#0:Codec: ATI R6xx HDMI
/proc/asound/card2/codec#0:Codec: Realtek ALC236
```

it does not appear in alsamixer:

[image]

I've tried tinkering with `hda-jack-retask` and with module options for the `snd-hda-intel` module (as recommended e.g. [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2151473#p2151473)), but it does not help.

Under Windows it works perfectly, then I know it's not a hardware problem. What else can I do?

Comment: File a bug report here: bugzilla.kernel.org, make sure you've attached `alsa-info.sh` output.